# How can I choose a random role and give it to a user Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Right now my code chooses a random role with `Math.Random` and can display it in the console but I don't know how to add that random role to a user.

```
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Choices.length);

console.log(Choices[random])
```

That's the code that chooses the role and displays it in the console, Choices are the different roles to select from.

```
await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add();
```

If I add the constant **`random`**, as the role to add it doesn't detect it as a role.
Please help, thanks.

This is the code

```
        const GRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Green");
        const BRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Blue");
        const RRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Red");
        const YRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Yellow");

        const RandomEmoji = '';

        const Choices = [
            "GRole",
            "BRole",
            "RRole",
            "YRole",
        ];


        const rereg = (args[0] === "reregister");

        if (!rereg) {

            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#cf44c9')
                .setTitle('Random Role⠀⠀')

            let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
            messageEmbed.react(RandomEmoji);

            client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
                if (user.bot) return;
                if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

                if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === RandomEmoji) {
                        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Choices.length);
                        console.log(Choices[random])

                        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add();
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Can we see the structure of your "Choices" array?

Comment: I added my code, please take a look.

Comment: Don’t you have to specify which role to add?

Comment: Yes but if I add random which is the randomly selected role it isn't identified as a role.

Comment: Hey what about the fact that the array is made up of strings instead of roles?

Answer (score 0):

in order to assign a role to a user you can use the following code:

**(Assuming that the constant "random" is a random index from "Choices". And "Choices" is an array of roles)**

```
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === Choices[random]);
message.member.addRole(role);
```